# Numerical integration using Simpson's Rule on discrete data

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I am looking for numerical integration with matlab. I know that there is a trapz function in matlab but the precision is not good enough. By searching it online, I found there is a quad function there it seems only accept symbolic expression as input. My data is all discrete and one-dimensional. Is that any way to use quad on my data? Thanks.

Comment: `quad()` is an implementation of Simpson's rule, which is high-school maths. Is there anything stopping you from implementing Simpson's rule yourself?

Comment: is it only use the simpson's rule, I think it is adaptive Simpson quadrature. But anyway, I don't know why, quad is fast than my implementation. I have so many data to integrate and looking for a faster way.

Comment: It's been a few years since my numerical methods course, but IIRC the only difference between regular Simpson's rule and the adaptive kind is that Adaptive Simpson's rule applies a variable spacing of the sampling points. Since you're not integrating a symbolic expression you can't vary the sampling interval - you already have your data and you can't interpolate more points between it. Therefore regular Simpson's rule will be as good as you can get.

Comment: Regarding the speed: Have you considered using the parallel execution tools available in new versions of MATLAB? The parallel for loop, `parfor`, is dead easy to use and will spread your CPU load over as many cores (or execution nodes) as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer to your question would be no. The only way to perform numerical integration for data with no expression in Matlab is by using the `trapz` function. If it's not accurate enough for you, try writing your own quad function as Li-aung said, it's very simple, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule) may help.

Another method you may try is to use the powerful Curve Fitting Tool `cftool` to make a fit then use the `integrate` function which can operate on `cfit` objects (it has a weird convention, the upper limit is the first argument!). I don't think you will get much accurate answers than `trapz`, it depends on the fit.

Answer (score 0):

Use the spline function in MATLAB to interpolate your data, then integrate this data. This is the standard method for integrating data in discrete form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `quadl()` to integrate your data if you first create a function in which you interpolate them.

```
function f = int_fun(x,xdata,ydata)
f = interp1(xdata,ydata,x);
```

And then feed it to the `quadl()` function:

```
integral = quadl(@int_fun,A,B,[],[],x,y) % syntax to pass extra arguments
                                         % to the function
```

Answer (score -1):

Integration of a function of one variable is the computation of the area under the curve of the graph of the function.  For this answer I'll leave aside the nasty functions and the corner cases and all the twists and turns that trip up writers of numerical integration routines, most of which are probably not relevant here.

Simpson's rule is an approach to the numerical integration of a function for which you have a code to evaluate the function at points within its domain.  That's irrelevant here.

Let's suppose that your data represents a time series of values collected at regular intervals.  Then you can plot your data as a histogram with bars of equal width.  The integrand you seek is the sum of the areas of the bars in the histogram between the limits you are interested in.

You should be able to apply this approach to data sets where the x-axis (ie the width of the bars in the histogram) does not show time, to the situation where the bars are not of equal width, to the situation where the data crosses the x-axis, and most reasonable data sets, quite easily.

The discretisation of your data establishes a limit to the accuracy of the result you can get.  If, for example, your time series is sampled at 1sec intervals you can't integrate over an interval which is not a whole number of seconds by this approach.  But then, you don't really have the data on which to compute a figure with any more accuracy by any approach.  Sure, you can use Matlab (or anything else) to generate extra digits of precision but they don't carry any meaning.

Comment: Simpson's rule can be done for fixed sample points too: for example, [scipy has an implementation of it](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.simps.html#scipy.integrate.simps). Also, the histogram you're describing is a rectangular approximation, which is theoretically worse even than `trapz` for continuous functions; Simpson's rule or Romberg integration / etc can definitely beat that, even with fixed samples, for most functions.

Comment: Think about the case where you know your function is an `n`-degree polynomial; then `n` or more sample points are enough for perfect knowledge of the function and so to get unlimited accuracy, whereas your claim is that the rectangular approximation is the best you can possibly do, which is clearly false. Although you usually don't know that it's a polynomial, continuity assumptions (and e.g. Stone-Weierstrass, which says that *any* continuous function is the limit of a sequence of polynomials) mean that better approximations will get you better results.

Comment: @Dougal: if you want to make unfounded assumptions about the function from which the discrete data is sampled go right ahead. I did, I assumed that the function was not continuous or differentiable.

Comment: If you're not making any continuity assumptions, numerical integration is just impossible. How do you know there's not some ridiculous tiny spike in there? You don't, unless you assume it's not.