# Matlab: How to compute an integral of a dataset when the function of the data is unknown

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, if I am given a time series dataset in which the second column of values is a function of the times of the first column, and I need to integrate over the second column of values, how do I do that without a function?

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just use trapz function. This is in Octave but should be the same in Matlab which uses the trapezoidal method.

octave-3.6.2.exe:1> x=1:5
x =

1   2   3   4   5

octave-3.6.2.exe:2> y=x.*x
y =

```
1    4    9   16   25
```

octave-3.6.2.exe:3> Area=trapz(x,y)
Area =  42

Comment: Your suggestion seems to work reasonably well and is easy to perform.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. Also check out the Simpson rule.

"Z = SIMPS(X,Y) computes the integral of Y with respect to X using the Simpson's rule."

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB you can use the function

```
 cumtrapz(time,data)
```

which is the cumulative trapezoidal integration.
The 2 inputs are vectors having the same lenght.
In this way you can for example obtain the velocity integrating the acceleration. 
The output is a vector with the same length of the inputs.

**EDIT**

You can also have a look at what I answered here [Numerical integration using Simpson's Rule on discrete data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881430/numerical-integration-using-simpsons-rule-on-discrete-data/27170316#27170316)